# How can I divide images include resources into devices ?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

Hi I'm making an Universal App.

My App is included many and large Images.

But, Images for ipad are useless at iphone.

Images for iphone are useless at ipad, too.

Just App size increase.

I want to divide images into devices (iphone, ipad).

[iOS Application Target is Universal]-[Devices] is set  'Universal'.

How can I divide images include resources into devices ?

If not is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the point of a Universal app is to have everything included. AFAIK, there is no way to separate images for a universal app, also for universal apps, the splash images need to be shipped altogether. Else, you will have to look into the option of separate iPad & iPhone apps.

Comment: I may not have been clear about the option of separate apps, I was referring to iPhone & iPad targets.. :) If my post answers your question (in case you do not want to wait for more replies) then kindly mark my answer as accepted answer. Thanks!